# Error in add and multply, pattern model, view, controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller

i have a problem with some math's operations in my program, i use the pattern Model–view–controller, so the important here is the model and the controller. The error appear in add and multiply.

My program do the operations, and the result for add is: 4x elevado a 1 /
and the result for multiply is: 2x elevado a 2

But that's results are incorrect, the correct answer for add(sumar) must be 2x elevado a 1 and for multiply(multiplicar) must be 1x elevado 2. I aport my class Model and Controller.

```
public class Model
```

{

```
int valor;
int orden;

public Model()
{
    this.valor=0;
    this.orden=0;
}
public Modelo(int val, int ord)
{
    this.valor=val;
    this.orden=ord;
}

public String mostrarMonomio(Modelo m)
{
    String cadena = null;
    cadena = m.valor+"x elevado a "+m.orden;
    return (cadena);
}
//function for add
public Modelo sumaMonomio(Modelo m)
{
    if(this.orden==m.orden)
    {
        return (new Modelo (this.valor+m.valor, this.orden));
    }
    else
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
//Function for multiply
public Modelo multiplicarMonomio(Modelo m)
{
    return (new Modelo (this.valor*m.valor, this.orden+m.orden));
}
```

}
Part of my controller

```
if(objvista.btnOperar2.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio1.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio1.getText()));
        objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio2.getText()));


        if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Sumar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.sumaMonomio(objmodelo);
        }

        else if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Multiplicar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.multiplicarMonomio(objmodelo);

        }
        objvista.txtResultado2.setText(objmodelo.mostrarMonomio(objmodelo.sumaMonomio(objmodelo)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found some issue in this code block you mentioned above

```
objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio1.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio1.getText()));

// it overrides the above instance creation
objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio2.getText()));
```

Since the second statement overrides the first statement due to which the output is different than expected because the `objmodelo` object has values assigned from second statement.

Also use `equals` than `==` because `==` acts differently for `String` in java i.e. `==` checks String object reference not the value.

For your reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

Comment: sorry for the delay, you were right, I couldn't see the error, thank you very much